# While connected to Elasticsearch through port-forwarding, can't communicate with ES

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have followed this [article](https://ict.swisscom.ch/2018/04/building-the-elk-stack-on-our-new-elasticsearch/) and connected to remote ES through the following command:

```
cf ssh my-logstash -L 9200:ES_HOST:443 -L 9201:ELK:59464 -i 0
```

Unlike ELK, I can't communicate with the new ES.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: did you properly replace ES_HOST and ELK with the appropriate DNS names?
Do you use SSL to connect to the (new) ES_HOST?

Comment: No I didn't use DNS names. I do approve insecure connection to ES_HOST. But now I'm getting "Unknown cluster".
I guess this is because I don't have an index pattern created through Kibana. 
To make the connection work, I added 's' to http and used username and password fetched from `cf env app-with-elasticearch-binding`
I wanted to avoid adding Kibana service but it turns out it's not possible.
The actual command is as following:
`curl -k https://full_access_username:full_access_password@localhost:9202/_cat/indices`

Comment: There are two problems with your approach: 1. The new ES is only listening to HTTPS, so you must use SSL. 2. The "Unknown Cluster" message means that you did not provide the proper hostname in the HTTP header. You must use DNS names as ES_HOST and ELK are non resolvable values.

Comment: If by "use SSL", you mean providing the certificate, I've downloaded from the app a random certificate **Swisscom_Root_CA_1.crt** to use alongside the curl command. However I get the error:
`curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'` which makes sense.

Comment: No you must use https, there is no need for providing a certificate. Did you add the appropriate /etc/hosts entries as described in the article?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I did the configuration of hosts. I noticed that there was an error in my command for creating the "cf cups", because I used the sign '@' in the username field.

Is it necessary to stop the elk host in order to have logstash handling logs?

Comment: You cannot 'stop' the ELK host as its a managed service but to establish a connection you'll need a proper service-binding to bosh services on the app you're using for the tunneling. After creating the service-bindings the app must be restaged.

Comment: I manage to make it work. Thank you. The problem was happening with Create User Provided Service. It's very strict with both username and password. I had to remove characters '!' or/and '#' from password.